# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$ in scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I have built a Spark project with SBT, Scala in intelliJ and written the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark =
      SparkSession
        .builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate();

  }
}
```

and get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$
    at com.bigdata.Main$.main(Main.scala:6)
    at com.bigdata.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

my bulid.stb :

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.0" % "provided"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.0"


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "untitled",
    idePackagePrefix := Some("com.bigdata")
  )
```

I see SPARK_HOME in path and it is fine
I tried to open another project and still has the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `spark-sql` dependency as `provided` so by default it will not be in the classpath when you execute the code locally.

You can either remove the provided scope if your intention is to just test things out or alternatively you can setup your IDE to include the provided dependencies also. In IntelliJ, this can be done from the run configuration options.

Comment: Provided dependency are not included when packaging but they do are present when testing from the IDE. It's not clear from OP how the code is run.